# Can I automatically populate a lookup field based on the most recently created record within a Type?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.CampaignMemberContactId}' + '_lkid').value = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.ContactId}';
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.CampaignMemberContactId}' + '_lkold').value = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.ContactName}';
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.CampaignMemberContactId}' + '_mod').value = 1;
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.CampaignMemberContactId}').value = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.ContactName}';
```

This is JavaScript being used on my Visualforce page to automatically populate the Contact Id lookup field.

I´d like to do the same for the Campaign Id lookup field, except that it wouldn´t be using the current page.

The idea is that the Campaign Id field would be populated depending on which value in the "Type" picklist field (on my vf page) is chosen; and once it had been chosen, the most recently created Campaign within that Type would appear in the field.

So for example, Type "A" has two Campaigns assigned to it: "Campaign 2015" and "Campaign 2016". If "A" is selected from the Type picklist, then the Campaign Id field is populated with "Campaign 2016".

Is this doable, without using a trigger or controller?

Comment: trigger doesn't come into this situation. You can put your logic in controller

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the javascript connectionJS and apexJS to accomplish this. You have to query in the javascript and get the related campaignID and other details. Here is the code which queries the **contact** records. You can change the code to match your requirements.

```
<apex:page>
  <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.connectionJS}"/> 
  <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.apexJS}"/> 
  <script>
      sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}'; 
      var ContactRec = sforce.connection.query('SELECT id,LastName FROM Contact limit 10');
      records = ContactRec.getArray('records');

  for (var i=0; i< records.length; i++) {
    var record = records[i];
    alert('Contact Lastname'+ record.lastName + 'Contact Id — ' + record.Id);

  }
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks, that´s helpful. One thing though: how have you been able to use connectionjs and apexjs (I get an error, whether I type it as connectionJS, connection.js or connection. It seems to think the files don´t exist)?  is there a way to access those files, so as to know what to type?

Comment: Try `<script src="/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/soap/ajax/28.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` if you don't want to create the static resource. If you need these files, just paste the path `/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js` to your salesforce home page URL truncating the last everything after.com. Same applies to apexJS.